# Warning weird: is declared but its value is never read

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

This is my code:'Skeleton' is declared but its value is never read.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    FlatList, View, StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
// But warning here 
import { Skeleton, Colors } from '@momo-platform/component-kits';

const SkeletonLoadingChat = () => {
    const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    return (
        <FlatList
            style={{ padding: 15 }}
            data={data}
            ListHeaderComponent={() => {
                return (
                    <View style={styles.headerSkelation}>
                        <View style={styles.avataSkelation} />
                        <View style={styles.lineSkelation} />
                    </View>
                );
            }}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                return (
                    // I used Skeleton here
                    <Skeleton.Custom
                        left={<Skeleton.Media size={52} />}
                        style={styles.skeletionItem}
                    >
                        <Skeleton.Line style={styles.width_1_9} />
                        <Skeleton.Line style={styles.width_80} />
                    </Skeleton.Custom>
                );
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

[image]

I used Skeleton but it still shows a warning
Interface Skeleton

```
export interface Skeleton extends SkeletonProps {
  Line?: React.ReactElement,
  Media?: React.ReactElement,
  Custom?: React.ReactElement,
}
```

If I remove import Skeleton it shows error
[image]

Comment: How can `Skeleton` be an interface when you use the *value* `Skeleton.Custom`?

Comment: Do you get an error if you remove the import? If so, which one?

Comment: Yes if I remove the import app show error

Comment: @Bergi in Skeleton I see property custom

Comment: My guess would be that the `@momo-platform/component-kits` type declarations are faulty and use `interface` for what should be a `namespace`. Unfortunately, I cannot find their source code online to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore this warning.

Comment: I usually refactor code so if I'm not careful I can remove Skeleton :(